# Get portion of each file name in a directory

Tags: php

I have a directory and want to get only portions of the file name for all files in that directory.

For example, if I have a directory with the following files:

```
file_a1.php
file_b2.php
file_c3.php
```

I want to get an array...

```
Array
(
    [0] => a1
    [1] => b2
    [2] => c3
)
```

...from the files in the directory.

Currently I'm using glob() as such:

```
$files = glob(__DIR__ . '/directory/file_*.php');
```

Then looping over each value in the array and stripping '/directory/file_' from the start and '.php' from the end of each string. Surely there is a better way to do this? Other than what I've been doing or using Regex to select what I want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) :

```
$files = array(
        __DIR__ . '/directory/file_a1.php',
        __DIR__ . '/directory/file_a2.php',
        __DIR__ . '/directory/file_a3.php');
$new_files = array();

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $new_files[] = str_replace(array(__DIR__ . '/directory/file_', '.php'), '', $file);
}

var_dump($new_files);
```

Result :

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'a1' (length=2)
  1 => string 'a2' (length=2)
  2 => string 'a3' (length=2)
```

Comment: This is exactly how I'm doing it at the moment ;) Looks like there may not be a better way...

Comment: You could also use a regex with [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), but I don't know if the performance will be better. I have chunks of code similar to yours, and I use str_replace.